Use accessibility chrome extension in Electron
I'm trying to install these estensions to test accessibility of an application built with Electron and Angular
https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/silktide-accessibility-ch/mpobacholfblmnpnfbiomjkecoojakah
https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/accessibility-insights-fo/pbjjkligggfmakdaogkfomddhfmpjeni
Reading the documentation I wrote this bunch of code in my main js file (referring to the second extensions listed above)
app.whenReady().then(() => {    

    session.defaultSession
      .loadExtension(
        'C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 1\\Extensions\\pbjjkligggfmakdaogkfomddhfmpjeni\\2.44.0_0'
      ).then((extension) => {
        console.log('Extension loaded', extension);
      }
});

when running the application I see the 'Extension loaded' message in console, indicating that the extensions has been succesfully loaded, but I cannot find any way to "launch" it from the browser, I mean something similar of what I can do using chrome

Is Electron still limited in chrome extension support?
I expect to have a way to launch the extension as I can do from Chrome

https://medium.com/p/2929bf937eb3
